# Tablesorter – Filter cells with multiple values

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am trying to customize the filter function of my Tablesorter table. I have a table which may in some cases contain multiple values (often one or two numbers) separated by a comma.

A column may look like this:

```
40
32
31,36
33
31,42
36
42
41,42
```

Now if I filter this column I with for example 36 - 42  I want the column with value "31,42" to remain.

I think it can be basic, just split the value and compare the input to the two values. But I can't find a suitable function to hook into. Any ideas?

*Updated*

I have this parser to enable sorting of my comma separated column

```
        $.tablesorter.addParser(
          id: 'comma-number'
          format: (s) ->
            lNumber = parseFloat(s.replace(/,/g, '.'))
            return lNumber
          type: 'numeric'
        )
```

What I want to do is compare the input in a filter searchbox against two values. Is there a way to get a hold of the input value in a filter event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that when tablesorter parses numeric table cell content, it ignores commas (when the [`usNumberFormat` option](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#usnumberformat) is `true`. So the parsed result of `31,42` is `3142`.

The solution would be to set the parser on that column to `text`, and set the filter to "match"

```
<th class="sorter-text filter-match">Numeric</th>
```

Then in the filter, search using the [`" or "` operator](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-filter.html#notes): `"31 or 42"` or `"31|42"`

This only needs a basic initialization code ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2426/)):

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    theme: 'blue',
    widgets: ['zebra', 'filter'],
    widgetOptions : {
        filter_reset: '.reset'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hello Mottie! Thanks for your reply. I will try this. Would that also support a range filter? I.e. "31 - 42"

Comment: Did you try it? ;) LOL I guess it "sorta" works... it shows the numbers from `31 - 42`, but it seems to think that `"31,42"` isn't one of those numbers. Honestly, I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: Yes tried it now. And yes it works "sorta". Some values disappear which is not so good lol. I will keep looking for a solution.

Comment: If you have time please se my edit above. Your solution gave me a new idea. Maybe it's possible to compare the input in a filter against an array of values?

Comment: How would you sort that cell then? By the first array value, or the lowest array value?

Comment: By the first value is fine in our case. The lowest value will always be first in this case as well so it would be the same. If it would be possible to get the input value in the addParser function I could compare it to parameter "s". ?

Comment: I think this will require some changes to the filter widget so that it can search through an array within the table cache; this will also improve how the filter interacts with child rows - please keep track of the progress of these changes from [this issue](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/574)

Comment: Ok that sounds really great! So you think it would be a good solution to hook into the parser and apply custom logic? Also, how do I get the input from a filter input to a function? I failed to find this in the documentation. Many thanks Mottie!